# iOS Local Notification / Background Activity

Tags: ios, background-process, uilocalnotification

I have the code below in my AppDelegate.m applicationDidEnterBackground which will display a local notification 10 seconds after closing the app.

However, the time stamp (and any other data I want to include) is whatever it is at the time of creating the notification.

I would like to be able to show the latest data at the point of displaying the notification, as opposed to the data at the time of creating it.

Can I do this with the notification, or do I need to do something with background activity? And if so, what do I call / how in order to schedule that activity?

```
NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh-mm-ss"];
NSString *resultString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: currentTime];

NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Time: %@",resultString]);

NSDate *alertTime = [[NSDate date]
                     dateByAddingTimeInterval:10];
UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
UILocalNotification* notifyAlarm = [[UILocalNotification alloc]
                                    init];
if (notifyAlarm)
{
    notifyAlarm.fireDate = alertTime;
    notifyAlarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    notifyAlarm.repeatInterval = 0;
    notifyAlarm.alertBody = resultString;
    [app scheduleLocalNotification:notifyAlarm];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK you are not able to show dynamic data in local notifications. If that dynamic data comes from server, then I'd suggest to use push notifications and build their messages with that dynamic data.

If your app is VoIP or Location-based app you can use corresponding background modes and then schedule local notification as soon as new data was polled.

Comment: It is actually a step counter. What I was looking to do was schedule a daily notification to show the number of steps done the previous day. However, to do that, I would need to grab the latest data, as opposed the the data at last launch. I know some apps sen to wake in order to collect latest data and save it to history etc., so how could I do it that way? Waking the app once a day for 1 or 2 seconds at the most, grabbing the latest data and posting a notification (and for that matter saving the latest data!).

Comment: Can you give some details how app is counting steps? Does it count them only when in foreground? For now I suppose that you should try using Location background mode and there on location update decide whether app should schedule a local notification

Comment: I am using CMCoreMotion CMStepCounter. So it gathers data all the time, and I just update the display & do relevant calculations when in foreground. So the data is available, but I need to process it before setting the local notification.

Comment: I've reviewed iOS app background modes one more time and haven't found any information what mode should be used to get core motion updates.
I'd propose to submit a support ticket to Apple on this matter.

Comment: thanks for this. It is a strange one isn't it? I think maybe you are right. There does seem to be no definitive answer on here or anywhere else. There seems to be 'hacks' but when the functionality such as core motion exists, you would think they would allow for it to be used in the background?!